# Two paths intersect at $75^\circ$. A location is $6$km from one path and $12$km from the intersection. How far is it from the other path?

Tags: trigonometry

> Two paths intersect at $75^\circ$. One location is at $6$km from one path and $12$km from the intersection. How far is that location from the other path?

I drew it, and the first problem that comes to mind is which of the 2 pairs of angles are $75^\circ$? Even when I pick I can hardly see anything useful I can do. Any hints?

Comment: there is only one angle which is 75, at the vertex where your two lines intersect. Then the segment which is 12km long splits that 75 into two (not necessarily equal) parts, but you are not told what they are - you have to figure that out

Comment: these kinds of problems are most efficiently solve using the law of sines/cosines (a.k.a. sine/cosine rule). Focus first on the triangle about which you know the most. Generally three elements in it (e.g. 2 sides and an angle) are enough to find all the others

Comment: Exactly. Thats what I got on my drawing. But thats where the problem starts haha

Comment: Can I calculate c with Pythagoreans theorem then use $\frac {b}{\sin b} = \frac{c}{\sin c}$ ?

Comment: yes, that might be useful - that is the sine rule; but I don't know what exactly you call b and c. And definitely avoid calling two different things with the same symbol!

Answer (score 2):

To get you started:

You have one triangle with sides $6$, $12$, and an angle of $90^\circ$. Normally this situation (2 sides and an angle **not** between them) calls for a sine rule, but because the triangle is right, we can start straight from the definition of sine: if the angle across from the side of length $6$ is $A$, then $\sin A = 6/12 = 1/2$ from which $A = 30^\circ$.

Comment: Got the result! Thanks a bunch!